# toggle div next to clicked div from many div having same class

Tags: jquery

i want to toggle ul next to clicked tag from many ul having same class just like this

```
 <ul class="section menu">

   <li>
     <a href="#" class="menuitem">Menu 1</a>

      <ul class="submenu">
        <li> <a>Submenu 1</a> </li>
     </ul>
   </li>

   <li>
     <a href="#" class="menuitem">Menu 2</a>

      <ul class="submenu">
        <li> <a>Submenu 1</a> </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

i am using following jquery but its not working

```
$('.menuitem').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $($(this).attr('ul')).toggle(300);
});
```

Comment: That should not toggle anything because `$(this).attr('ul')` will probably return an empty string. jQuery has great documentation, have a look at the traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/. Your title does not seem to match your problem btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.menuitem').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next("ul.submenu").toggle(300);
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/m3v2X/)